# $\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{2} )$ and $\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{3}) $ are isomorphic as fields?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

$\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{2} )$  and $\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{3}) $ are isomorphic as fields ?
I think they are ring isom with ring hom which sends $\sqrt{2}$ to $\sqrt{3}$.

Then, number of quadratic extensions of $\mathbf{Q}$ is just one up to field isomorphisms ?? (but there are infinitely many number of quadratic extensions as sets)

Is my understanding right?

Thank you for your correction.

Comment: One of them contains a square root of $2$, the other doesn't.

Comment: The map sending sqrt(2) to sqrt(3) is an isomorphism of Q-vector spaces, not of fields. This map does not preserve multiplication.

Comment: When you define a ring homomorphism by defining where it sends generators, you need to make sure that any relation satisfied by generators must also correspond to a "homomorphic" relation satisfied by their images. If you map $\sqrt{2}$ to $\sqrt{3}$, then you have a problem in extending this to a ring homomorphism, since $\sqrt{2}$ satisfies $x^2 - 2 = 0$, while $\sqrt{3}$ does not.